# Pandas backfilling data on multi-index on dates

Tags: pandas

Original

```
user_id date        had_session made_an_order
1       2016-03-01  True        True
        2016-03-02  True        True
        2016-03-03  True        False

2       2016-03-01  True        True       
        2016-03-02  True        True       
        2016-03-04  True        False       

3       2016-03-01  True        False       
        2016-03-04  True        False
```

Backfilled data

```
user_id date        had_session made_an_order
1       2016-03-01  True        True       
        2016-03-02  True        True       
        2016-03-03  True        False       
        2016-03-04  False       False     # backfilled row

2       2016-03-01  True        True       
        2016-03-02  True        True       
        2016-03-03  False       False    # backfilled row
        2016-03-04  True        False           

3       2016-03-01  True        False       
        2016-03-02  False       False           # backfilled row
        2016-03-03  False       False           # backfilled row
        2016-03-04  True        False
```

My data has two levels: first level is `user_id` and second level is whether they had session.

I want to make sure that the data is backfilled such that, second level contains every date possible and default to false

e.g. the possible dates are from 2016-03-01 to 2016-03-04. So I want to make sure every user_id has all those dates

Answer (score 2):

You can first [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), then [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and last [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
print (df.reset_index()
         .pivot(index='date',columns='user_id',values='had_session')
         .fillna(False)
         .unstack()
         .reset_index(name='had_session'))

    user_id        date had_session
0         1  2016-03-01        True
1         1  2016-03-02        True
2         1  2016-03-03        True
3         1  2016-03-04       False
4         2  2016-03-01        True
5         2  2016-03-02        True
6         2  2016-03-03       False
7         2  2016-03-04        True
8         3  2016-03-01        True
9         3  2016-03-02       False
10        3  2016-03-03       False
11        3  2016-03-04        True
```

Explanation:

```
#remove multiindex
print (df.reset_index())
   user_id        date had_session
0        1  2016-03-01        True
1        1  2016-03-02        True
2        1  2016-03-03        True
3        2  2016-03-01        True
4        2  2016-03-02        True
5        2  2016-03-04        True
6        3  2016-03-01        True
7        3  2016-03-04        True

#pivot table - get NaN in missing values
print (df.reset_index()
         .pivot(index='date',columns='user_id',values='had_session'))
user_id        1     2     3
date                        
2016-03-01  True  True  True
2016-03-02  True  True  None
2016-03-03  True  None  None
2016-03-04  None  True  True

#replace NaN to False
print (df.reset_index()
         .pivot(index='date',columns='user_id',values='had_session')
         .fillna(False))
user_id         1      2      3
date                           
2016-03-01   True   True   True
2016-03-02   True   True  False
2016-03-03   True  False  False
2016-03-04  False   True   True
```

```
#create multiindex         
print (df.reset_index()
         .pivot(index='date',columns='user_id',values='had_session')
         .fillna(False)
         .unstack())
user_id  date      
1        2016-03-01     True
         2016-03-02     True
         2016-03-03     True
         2016-03-04    False
2        2016-03-01     True
         2016-03-02     True
         2016-03-03    False
         2016-03-04     True
3        2016-03-01     True
         2016-03-02    False
         2016-03-03    False
         2016-03-04     True
dtype: bool
```

Solution with 2 columns:

```
df1 = (df.reset_index()
         .pivot_table(index='date',columns='user_id',values=['had_session', 'made_an_order'])
         .fillna(False))

df2 = (df1.had_session)

df3 = (df1.made_an_order)

print (pd.concat([df2.unstack(),df3.unstack()], 
                 axis=1,
                 keys=['had_session','made_an_order']))
                   had_session made_an_order
user_id date                                
1       2016-03-01        True          True
        2016-03-02        True          True
        2016-03-03        True         False
        2016-03-04       False         False
2       2016-03-01        True          True
        2016-03-02        True          True
        2016-03-03       False         False
        2016-03-04        True         False
3       2016-03-01        True         False
        2016-03-02       False         False
        2016-03-03       False         False
        2016-03-04        True         False
```

Another solution with double `pivot`:

```
df2 = (df.reset_index()
         .pivot(index='date',columns='user_id',values='had_session')
         .fillna(False))

df3 = (df.reset_index()
         .pivot(index='date',columns='user_id',values='made_an_order')
         .fillna(False))

print (pd.concat([df2.unstack(),df3.unstack()], 
                 axis=1,
                 keys=['had_session','made_an_order']))

                   had_session made_an_order
user_id date                                
1       2016-03-01        True          True
        2016-03-02        True          True
        2016-03-03        True         False
        2016-03-04       False         False
2       2016-03-01        True          True
        2016-03-02        True          True
        2016-03-03       False         False
        2016-03-04        True         False
3       2016-03-01        True         False
        2016-03-02       False         False
        2016-03-03       False         False
        2016-03-04        True         False
```

Comment: Hey jezrael, this works and is the correct answer. Can you explain a little the magic that you are doing? :)

Comment: Also, in my actual problem, I had 2 columns (had_session, made_an_order). How do I go about handling both columns?

Comment: Both columns are boolean?

Comment: Yes both columns are booleans, and I updated the question to reflect that

Comment: Also, after the unstack, the last column, does not seem to have column name. How do I go about adding the column name back?

Comment: Yes, I add missing column name in  1. solution and solution with 2 columns.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

source DF

```
In [370]: a
Out[370]:
                   had_session made_an_order
user_id date
1       2016-03-01        True          True
        2016-03-02        True          True
        2016-03-03        True         False
2       2016-03-01        True          True
        2016-03-02        True          True
        2016-03-04        True         False
3       2016-03-01        True         False
        2016-03-04        True         False
```

prepare a DF with a MultiIndex, containing a product of user_id's and dates:

```
In [371]: df = pd.DataFrame(
   .....:   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
   .....:     a.index.get_level_values('user_id').unique().tolist(),
   .....:     a.index.get_level_values('date').unique().tolist()
   .....:   ])
   .....: )
```

set the index names from the original/source DF

```
In [372]: df.index.names=a.index.names
```

join

```
In [374]: df.join(a, how='left').fillna(False)
Out[374]:
                   had_session made_an_order
user_id date
1       2016-03-01        True          True
        2016-03-02        True          True
        2016-03-03        True         False
        2016-03-04       False         False
2       2016-03-01        True          True
        2016-03-02        True          True
        2016-03-03       False         False
        2016-03-04        True         False
3       2016-03-01        True         False
        2016-03-02       False         False
        2016-03-03       False         False
        2016-03-04        True         False
```